# string number with comma's to integer with comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, integer, converters

The problem when I'm converting string in an array to integers in an array is that the numbers are rounded. See my code and comments

```
console.log(rating); // ["6.4", "7.4", "6.3"] 

//convert to integer
for (v = 0; v < rating.length; v++) {
rating[v] = (parseInt(rating[v])); //<< here it goes wrong I think..
console.log(rating); 
}

rating.sort()
console.log(rating) //expect to see [6.4, 6.3, 7.4]
//what I see [6, 6, 7]
```

How does this happen and how can i fix this?!

Comment: use just `Number(rating[v])`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=integer

Comment: Please check the documentation before asking. [ParseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and [ParseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseInt` gives you an integer, if you want to keep decimals you can either use

```
parseFloat(rating[v])
```

Or:

```
Number(rating[v])
```

Comment: Thanks it works.. couldn't believe it was that simple :)